# Parallel.For with value producing iterations and cache line sharing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I found link to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx) while was reading [Parallel Patterns](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/)

But I'm a little confused now.

What if every iteration of Parallel.For produces result and stores it as array's item.
There's no race condition and no need for synchronization. But cache line must be in sync with all threads what degrades performance. (If I'm not mistaken).

So I'm interested whether ways of performance improvement exist.

Comment: What kind of explanations are you looking for? Or are you just asking how to avoid false sharing? Didn't the article explain that?

Comment: I ask how to avoid sharing and whether it is possible to do for Parallel.For when each iteration has to return some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if every iteration of Parallel.For produces result and stores it
>   as array's item.

In order for false sharing to occur you'd need different threads to access array items that are near to each other.

In practice, you have a small number of threads (let's call it C) processing a large array of size N, with N >> C. This means that each thread gets a reasonably large number of items to process. Assuming they can be processed independently, the ideal way to do it is by doing a contiguous split, thus each thread gets consecutive positions in the array. This avoids false sharing pretty well.

It wouldn't make sense to process array elements interleaved for example, because that would indeed cause false sharing. It may not always be possible to use the contiguous strategy however, because sometimes load-balancing comes into play. In this case you have to see which is more detrimental: occasional false sharing or bad load-balancing. The discussion is long. I'm sure the underlying TPL scheduler is designed well-enough to obtain the best trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's quite clear. But I'm curios is there any direct way to tell CLR to create the set of 100% NOT memory-adjacent objects. I understand it sounds a bit insane =) and feels like return to explicit memory management what is hardly reasonable. Still I'd call it an academic interest;)